# patterns unlock attempts by a BroadcastReceiver in android

Tags: android, broadcast

I am developing an Android application that captures the image of the user **trying to unlock the screen with patterns** and sent to a valid email.

The question is, how I can know how many failed attempts are logged
to a BroadcastReceiver?.

Answer (score 3):

> The question is how I can know how many failed attempts are logged to a BroadcastReceiver?.

You are welcome to use the [Device Administration APIs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) to find out about failed password attempts. In particular, [your properly-configured `DeviceAdminReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver.html) can be called with `onPasswordFailed()` on password failures. Note that I have not tried this with a simple pattern lock, so it's possible that this will only work with more serious device security (PIN, password).